# How to loop through a JSON array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to loop through a JSON array.

here is example output

```
{
    "calls": [
        [
            {
                "interactionId": "2002766591",
                "account_id": "",
                "mid": "",
                "Eic_CallDirection": "O",
                "Eic_RemoteAddress": "5462223378",
                "Eic_LocalAddress": "1062",
                "Eic_State": "I"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "status": [
        {
            "statusId": "Available",
            "userId": "su",
            "loggedIn": false
        }
    ]
}
```

here is my jQuery code.

```
<script>
$(function(){

    function isset(a, b){

        if(typeof a !== "undefined" && a){
            return a
        }

        return b;
    }

    setInterval(function() {

        $.getJSON("showMEssages.php", {method: "getMessages"}, function(data){

            if(data.calls.length == 0 || !data.calls){
                console.log('No Messages');
            }
            var c;

            $.each(data.calls, function(i, item){

                c = item[i];
                console.log(c);

                var interactionId = isset(c.interactionId, 0);
                var Eic_CallDirection = isset(c.Eic_CallDirection, '');
                var Eic_State = isset(c.Eic_State, '');
                var AccoRDI_mid = isset(c.AccoRDI_mid, '');
                var Eic_RemoteAddress = isset(c.Eic_RemoteAddress, '');

                if( Eic_CallDirection == 'I' && Eic_State == 'A'){
                    console.log('Call From ' + Eic_RemoteAddress + ' MID: ' + AccoRDI_mid );
                }

                if(Eic_CallDirection == 'O' && Eic_State == 'C'){
                    console.log('Live Call With ' + Eic_RemoteAddress );
                }


            });
        });

    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

my code is working but I get since it runs every second I keep getting this error in the logs

```
TypeError: c is undefined
```

and the error point to this line

```
console.log(c);
```

what is the cause of this issue and how can I correct it?

Comment: your code works for me in my fiddle, unless your actual json is not the one you posted http://jsfiddle.net/etuLsedk/

Answer (score 2):

In this function:

```
$.each(data.calls, function(i, item){});
```

`item` is the value of each element in `data.calls`, so you don't need to use `item[i]`. Just `c = item` is enough.

Comment: in his json, calls is an array of arrays, getting the ith element makes sense

Comment: `i` is the index of  `item` in `data.calls`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I had to do a loop with in a loop since I have array with in array

```
        $.each(data.calls, function(i, item){

            $.each(item, function(z, c){

                var interactionId = isset(c.interactionId, 0);
                var Eic_CallDirection = isset(c.Eic_CallDirection, '');
                var Eic_State = isset(c.Eic_State, '');
                var AccoRDI_mid = isset(c.AccoRDI_mid, '');
                var Eic_RemoteAddress = isset(c.Eic_RemoteAddress, '');

                if( Eic_CallDirection == 'I' && Eic_State == 'A'){
                    console.log('Call From ' + Eic_RemoteAddress + ' MID: ' + AccoRDI_mid );
                }

                if(Eic_CallDirection == 'O' && Eic_State == 'C'){
                    console.log('Live Call With ' + Eic_RemoteAddress );
                }

            });
        });
```